# ConstraintLayout Placeholder view does not override dimensions

Tags: android, xml, constraints, placeholder

I am trying to use the new constraint layout placeholder, but I am getting difficulties due to the fact that it won't work properly if width/height values other than 0 will be supplied to placeholder.

This is my child view that should inject a view into the template. Notice that width and height is set to match_constraint and wrap_content

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_height="30dp" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/view_full_screen_dialog_template"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is code I am using for my Placeholder

```
  <android.support.constraint.Placeholder
        android:id="@+id/template_dialog_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="asasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdf"
        app:content="@+id/dialog_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/w_buttons"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_title" />
```

As you can see I have laout_height set to wrap_content too and this(somewhy) forces layout in designer to be streched all across the view.

Problem is that the text view acts simply weird, getting cut, only taking 2dp of content. If i'd set width/height for placeholder to 0dp, it would work fine.

TL;DR can placeholder width/height values be different than 0 for it to work properly? And can they be overriden?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's your goal, but there are two issues on your code: (1) you didn't define a text in your TextView (but rather on the placeholder) and (2) I believe you need to remove the plus sign from `app:content="@+id/dialog_content"`.